# Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync fails when reload the frame

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, word-web-addins

I am implementing the pinnable taskpane in my outlook web add-in
This is my code:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Listen to ItemChanged event
        Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged, function (result) {
            console.log(result)
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                // here will be hit if I do a postback in the server, could also be replicated by choosing "reload frame" in the right click menu
             {name: "Internal Error", message: "An internal error has occurred.", code: 5001}
            }
        });
        gatherMailItemInfo();
    });
}
```

Everything works fine( `gatherMailItemInfo` get calls when I switching between items. But as long as a do a `post` to the server ( can simply replicated by choosing "reload frame" in the right click menu) the handler will fail.

I am using office 365 for testing. Windows desktop client has no such issues.

Comment: What client are you on? Windows Desktop? Mac Outlook? Outlook Web Access? (please also provide version number) I tried your example on recent versions of Windows Desktop and I couldn't get a repro. You may want to make sure you are updated to at least version: 16.0.10231.10000

Comment: Office 365.I just there is no version number for that? I just tested in windows desktop and yeah it has no issues.

Comment: Reload won't work in the add-in. You should not reload the view by any means. That's it.

Comment: This currently doesn't work in Outlook Web Access. It is unknown when this would be fixed. Right now the recommended work around is to not call "window.location.reload" or similar commands. It would help to understand your scenario and why this is necessary instead of handling the itemChanged event in another way.

Comment: See [my answer in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818398/outlook-webaddin-throwing-internal-server-error-when-registering-office-eventtyp/57733756#57733756).