# ItemChanged event in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

Hi I am building an outlook addin, I want to know if there is way to handle the ItemChange event, I know we can use it by pinning the taskpane, isn’t there any other way??

Answer (score 1):

Currently ItemChanged event can only be used in case of pinned add-in. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [addHandlerAsync(eventType, handler, [options], [callback])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback) method to subscribe to the `ItemChange` event. Here is what MSDN states:

> Currently the only supported event type is Office.EventType.ItemChanged, which is invoked when the user selects a new item. This event is used by add-ins that implement a pinnable task pane, and allows the add-in to refresh the task pane UI based on the currently selected item.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
 $(document).ready(function () {
   Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, loadNewItem, function (result) {
     if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      // Handle error.
     }
   });
 });
};

function loadNewItem(eventArgs) {
  // Load the properties of the newly selected item.
  loadProps(Office.context.mailbox.item);
};
```

Also, you may find the following discussion helpful - [Outlook Add-In API does not fire the ItemChange event consistently on Firefox/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351654/outlook-add-in-api-does-not-fire-the-itemchange-event-consistently-on-firefox-ch). ItemChange fires when the item actually changes, but not when you simply change the selection.

Comment: Thanks, for suggesting this method, the use of this method requires us to implement pinnable taskpane which I am trying to avoid, is there any other way we can go about it ??

Comment: I don't think this is really required.

Comment: Permissions to read and the minimum mailbox requirement set version is 1.5.