# Trigger event on selection mail item or change selection of mail item

Tags: reactjs, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create a outlook plugin in React JS to detect mail selected or mail selection change.

Tried Mailbox EvenetType ItemChanged, add handler for event is return success but handler not called when user select or change selected mail from list.

The code I used is as below

```
Office.onReady(() => {
  // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
  Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, 
    (eventType) => mailItemChanged(eventType), 
    (AsyncResult) => {console.log(AsyncResult)});
});

function mailItemChanged(eventType) {
  console.log('Office.EventType.ItemChanged triggered');
}
```

Please let me if there is any other option  to trigger email selection change event

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing when you expect the itemchanged event to be fired?

Comment: Just to be specific, you are clicking on another read mail in the mail list, and the item is changing in the reading pane, but no item change event is fired to your add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev on every mail selection I need to check sender, subject and few other property of mail item. I need to get every Inboxed item details ..

Comment: You may find similar posts, for example, see [Outlook Add-In API does not fire the ItemChange event consistently on Firefox/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351654/outlook-add-in-api-does-not-fire-the-itemchange-event-consistently-on-firefox-ch).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook Add-In API does not fire the ItemChange event consistently on Firefox/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351654/outlook-add-in-api-does-not-fire-the-itemchange-event-consistently-on-firefox-ch)

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstafiev I tried the same url and same code is written but the handler is not triggered on switching of mail item.

Comment: Do you have a task pane displayed at this time?

Comment: Yes Task pane displayed and pinned.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Now it's working with pinned task pane, is there any way to trigger itemChanged event with pinned taskpane or ui-less event trigger.

Comment: It seems we have just found the cause why it wasn't triggered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event was introduced to update the pane when selection is changed. The web add-ins work under the context of item selected in Outlook. So, it is expected to get the event triggered when the task pane is pinned.